# Can't create typed shortcut for a type

Tags: typescript

I have a enumeration in TS 2.9:

```
export enum FMEvents {
  RECORD_ADDED = "@firemodel/RECORD_ADDED",
  RECORD_CHANGED = "@firemodel/RECORD_CHANGED",
  RECORD_MOVED = "@firemodel/RECORD_MOVED",
  RECORD_REMOVED = "@firemodel/RECORD_REMOVED",
}
```

It works just fine. I *was* struggling how to get the string values to be a constraint/type and thanks to [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) I was able to sort this out by doing the following:

```
export type Extractable<T, U> = T extends U ? any : never;
export type NotString<T> = string extends T ? never : any;
```

And now I can create a function like so:

```
doSomething<K extends string & NotString<K> & Extractable<FMEvents, K>>(type: K) { 
  //... 
}
```

Where the "type" is now properly constrained to the string *values* of the enumeration (such as "@firemodel/RECORD_ADDED", etc.). The only problem that remains is that type is needed throughout the code base and it's quite a mouthful so I figured I could give it a more descriptive name at the same time as decreasing the number of keystrokes needed to constrain in this way. Here's what I THOUGHT would work:

```
export type IFMEventName<T> = T extends string & NotString<T> & Extractable<FMEvents, T>;
```

But this gives me the following errors. Can anyone help me figure out what to do?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, that's not valid syntax:

```
type A = B extends C; // error, ? expected
```

The compiler is interpreting that as the beginning of a [conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) as in

```
type A = B extends C ? D : E;
```

and possibly is producing another error complaining about the unexportable nameless types in the missing `D` or `E` positions.  The error is a red herring, since you're not trying to use conditional types at all here.

---

It looks like you're trying to make a type alias for a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints), which is also not valid syntax... the generic parameter name and the `extends` keyword can't be moved to a type alias.

So I'm guessing you are trying this:

```
// can't do this
export type IFMEventName<T> = T extends string & NotString<T> & Extractable<FMEvents, T>;
// also can't do this
function doSomething<IFMEventName<K>>(type: K) { /*...*/ }
```

I'm surprised you're not seeing all kinds of other errors... or maybe you are?   Anyway, I think the closest you will get to what you want is:

```
export type IFMEventName<T> = string & NotString<T> & Extractable<FMEvents, T>;
function doSomething<K extends IFMEventName<K>>(type: K) { /*...*/ }
```

Hope that makes sense and works for you.  Good luck again!

Comment: Thanks! Our power just went out so can’t check it yet but your typing skills give me 100% confidence it’ll work.